# what is positive float and it includes 0?

Tags: numbers

I have a question.
Maybe it is simple.. but I wondered.

Is "Positive float" mean k>=0?
I want to ask positive float includes zero?

I wondered it because of Ridge regression hyper parameters tuning.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context. If we are talking about numbers having a type of float, then the float number is positive if its sign bit is 0:

> Sign bit s (bit 31). The most significant bit represents the sign of
>   the number (1 for negative, 0 for positive).

https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/

As a matter of fact, positive zero and negative zero are existent. Both are representing a number with an infinitely small absolute value, converging towards zero, but a positive zero is infinitely slightly bigger than 0 and a negative zero is infinitely slightly smaller than 0. Both positive and negative zero have all 0 values for all bits, except the sign bit. In the case of a sign bit, a positive zero's sign bit is 0, a negative zero's sign bit is 1.

However, if we talk about positive float, and negative float in general, we get scheduling concepts. In this context, a positive float means that there is excess time for an activity, while a negative float means that there is no excess time for an activity, so the activity has to start as soon as possible.